# How to compare two constraints of same fact in the drools-guvnor while making a rule

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

I have Fact - Orders
and two constraints under it :  Orders - > Account and Orders - > TargetAccount

I am making a rule inside free form DRL such that if Orders.Account.AccountNumber ! = Orders.TargetAccount.AccountNumber  then a specific PDF should be generated.

How to write this when condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it should be as simple as

```
when
  Orders.Account.AccountNumber ! = Orders.TargetAccount.AccountNumber
then
  // generate specific PDF
```

Or was the some details involved that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so it worked like this way : 
Orders (Account.AccountNumber != TargetAccount.AccountNumber)
I recommend to use minimum of || or && , instead use number of free form DRLs one below each other if OR conditions are not there . Try to avoid && , it creates issues specially when we have more than 2 AND conditions